# How to call a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there any other way to call a `UIViewCOntroller`, without the following;

```
HelloUIViewController *hello = [[HelloUIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:hello animated:YES];
```

The above code will set the view in a Navigation bar where you will get the `BackButton` as well (the arrow shaped button when you navigate from view to view).

I Just want to go to a new `UiviewController`, and do not want it to have a backButton (basically the `viewController` should not be pushed into the navigation stack)

Comment: Are you looking for a [modal view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)?

Comment: You may run into issues pushing your view without the nib name specified.

Comment: @BillBrasky What issues? If you don't specify the name, UIViewController's `-loadView` will look for a nib with a name that matches that of the view controller, i.e. HelloUIViewController.xib in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication applicationDelegate] window];
window.rootViewController = [[HelloUIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

Of course, it might not really be what you want. It'll install the view controller as the window's root view controller. If you want to keep your navigation controller and just show the new controller outside the navigation stack, you'll want to present the view controller modally. From another view controller, you can:

```
HelloUIViewController *hello = [[HelloUIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:hello animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: It should appear horizontally, like the pushviewcontroller. and not vertically.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you don't want to push it onto the nav stack? It sounds like you want it to *look* like it's part of the nav stack, and just not display the nav bar or back button. Hiding the nav bar and pushing normally as sch described is the easy way to do what you seem to want.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the navigationBar, present your ViewController modally.

```
[self presentModalViewController:helloViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Note that this method is not preferred by Apple as of iOS 5 (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Instead, use `presentViewController:animated:completion:`.

Comment: You are correct. Was just jotting down the one I had memorized =p

Comment: It should appear horizontally, like the pushviewcontroller. and not vertically.

Answer (score 1):

you can hide the navigation bar:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

Or if you want to keep the navigation bar but only get rid of the back button you can do something like this:

```
 self.navigationController.backItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```